# function satisfying $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(z,x,\theta)\:dz = e^{g(x, \theta)}$

Tags: integration

Suppose $z$, $x$, $\theta$ are real value, and $f(), g(), h(), l()$ are real-valued function.

Is there any function $f$ satisfying following equation?

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(z,x,\theta)\:dz = e^{g(x, \theta)}$

where $f(z,x,\theta)\neq h(z)l(x,\theta)$.

I tried to find primitive function which satisfy

$F(\infty , x, \theta)-F(-\infty,x,\theta)=e^{g(x, \theta)}$

but I couldn't.
Could anyone solve or give basic direction of solution?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
It's difficult to explain the condition of $f$.
$f(z,x,\theta)=\pi^{-1/2}e^{-(x-z)^2}e^{g(x,\theta)}$ is not the answer I want. $f(z,x,\theta)$ should include $e^{-(x-\mu(z))^2}$ where $\mu$ is the function parameterized by $\theta$, and $\mu(\infty)$ is unknown. Sorry for such complex condition and not mathematical definition.

Comment: How about $e^{-(z-x)^2}e^{g(x,\theta)}$ ?

Comment: >Ninad Munshi, Thank you for quick answer, but it's not the solution I want. Please read EDIT message.

Comment: your are talking about $\mu$, THE function parameterized by $\theta$. Are there any specifications to this $\mu$? Also what is the context of your question, that might help me and others to gain insight so what you want (as you said what you are currently asking for is very vague) :)

Comment: > C. Brendel. I opened another question with complete description [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400996/general-condition-of-function-f-satisfying-int-infty-inftyefx-zd). Please check it if you have time. Thank you anyway.