# General condition of function $f$ satisfying $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{f(x,z)}dz = e^{g(x)}$

Tags: integration

Suppose $x, z$ are real number, and suppose $f, g$ are real-valued function satisfying following equation

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{f(x,z)}dz = e^{g(x)}$.

Could anyone find general condition of $f$ ?

I noticed $e^{f(x,z)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{(x-z)^2}e^{g(x)}$ is an example of $f$ by using Gaussian integration, but I want to know general condition.

I asked similar question before, but my description was vague. Now I believe the description is enough to calculate general condition. If not, please comment. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $f(x,iz)=h(x)+g(z)$ with suitable $h$ satisfies this. It is unlikely that we can find a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: >Kabo Murphy Thank you. How about the case where $f(x,z) = h(x) + l(z) + m(x)n(z)$? When $m(x)n(z)=-2xz$, this is the example I gave.